# Simple networking behind a router without NAT and DHCP

Tags: nat, dhcp

I am novice to network engineering. I have two questions :

Is it possible to assign a fixed public Ip address to a pc directly  connected to a router without a dhcp and a NAT and having access to the internet.
I have tried to get connected to do this but did not work for me.

The second question is it  possible to put only an access point behind a router without NAT and DHCP and being able to provide internet access to wireless clients after activating the DHCP of the access point.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to assign a fixed public Ip address to a pc directly connected to a router without a dhcp and a NAT and having access to the internet. I have tried to get connected to do this but did not work for me.

Yes, assuming your ISP has assigned BOTH a range of addresses for your hosts AND a separate subnet for the link between you and the ISP.

> The second question is it possible to put only an access point behind a router without NAT and DHCP and being able to provide internet access to wireless clients after activating the DHCP of the access point.

Yes, as long as the DHCP server is configured to assign the correct IPs (see answer above).

If you include your router model and configuration, we can help you set this up.  Note that consumer-grade devices are off-topic for this forum